# Airflow - log the user who triggered the dag

Tags: logging, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I try to log the user who has triggered my DAG in the Airflow that terminates postgres hanging queries and it does not work. Can you please help what could be wrong? What am I missing? When I check the log in the airflow instead of the user name there is 'None' everywhere.

utils.py (where the session logic is described)

```py
import logging
from airflow.models.log import Log
from airflow.utils.db import create_session
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
from plugins.platform.kw_postgres_hook import KwPostgresHook


# To test this use this command:
# airflow tasks test killer_dag killer_query {date} -t '{"pid":"pid_value"}'
# Example :
# airflow tasks test killer_dag killer_query 20210803 -t '{"pid":"12345"}'


def kill_query(**kwargs):
    with create_session() as session:
        triggered_by = (
            session.query(Log.owner)
            .filter(
                Log.dag_id == "killer_dag",
                Log.event == "trigger",
                Log.execution_date == kwargs["execution_date"],
            )
            .limit(1)
            .scalar()
        )
    logging.info(
        f"'{triggered_by}' triggered the Killer_dag. Getting PID for the termination."
    )
    pid = kwargs["params"]["pid"]
    logging.info(f"This PID= '{pid}' is going to be terminated by '{triggered_by}'.")
    analdb_hook = KwPostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="anal_db")
    analdb_conn = analdb_hook.get_conn()
    analdb_cur = analdb_conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    # Termination query receives pid as a parameter from cli
    killer_query = f"""
        select pg_terminate_backend('{pid}');
    """
    logging.info(killer_query)
    # Making sure the user provides existing pid.
    # In this part the boolean result of terminating select is checked and if False error is raised.
    analdb_cur.execute(killer_query)
    result = analdb_cur.fetchone()
    exists = result["pg_terminate_backend"]
    if exists == True:
        logging.info(f"The pid = '{pid}' was terminated by '{triggered_by}'.")
    else:
        logging.info(f"The pid = '{pid}' not found, check it again!")
    return exists


def kill_hanging_queries(killer_dag):
    PythonOperator(
        task_id="kill_query",
        python_callable=kill_query,
        dag=killer_dag,
        provide_context=True,
    )
```

killer_dag.py

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from plugins.platform.utils import skyflow_email_list
from dags.utils.utils import kill_hanging_queries


killer_dag = DAG(
    dag_id="killer_dag",
    default_args={
        "owner": "Data Intelligence: Data Platform",
        "email": skyflow_email_list,
        "email_on_failure": True,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "start_date": datetime(2021, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0),
        "retries": 0,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1),
    },
)
kill_hanging_queries(killer_dag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `None` because the query does not return any results, so `scalar()` returns `None` as default value.

First of all, if you browse the logs from the Airflow UI (*Browse > Audit Logs*) and filter by `dag_id` and `event` you will notice that `execution_date` is always empty, and the datetime is registered under `Dttm` field:

[image: Audit Logs search]

Thats the main reason why you are not getting results, because when you filter by `Log.execution_date == kwargs["execution_date"]` never matches.

So in order to achieve what you are looking for, you could follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792198/10569220) where a similiar query is being perfomed. Taking that as a source, you could make something like the following to obtain the `owner` of the last *trigger* event (which is most likely the execution that is actually running) and avoid having to deal with dates as filter.

```py
triggered_by = (
    session.query(Log.dttm, Log.dag_id, Log.execution_date, Log.owner)
    .filter(Log.dag_id == "killer_dag", Log.event == "trigger")
    .order_by(Log.dttm.desc())
    .first()[3]
)
```

The above returns a tupple with the desired fields, being the third the `owner`.

Output:

`[2021-08-11 23:05:29,481] {killer_dag.py:41} INFO - This PID= '123' is going to be terminated by 'superUser'.`

### Edit:

Note:

Keep in mind that if you don't actually trigger the DAG (either manually or via the scheduler) there wont be any `Log` to query. Running `airflow tasks test ..` won't create any record with `Log.event == "trigger"`. So before further debugging, make sure that actually exists a `Log` entry to query, you can do it by browsing the UI as explained above.

In order to avoid `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` when there are no results in the query, you could change the query to use `scalar()` again:

```py
triggered_by = (
    session.query(Log.owner)
    .filter(Log.dag_id == "killer_dag", Log.event == "trigger")
    .order_by(Log.dttm.desc())
    .limit(1)
    .scalar()
)
```

Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your time and help!It does not work right now,I am going to check the error thoroughly, maybe it is just a matter of small adjustment now.

Comment: def kill_query(**kwargs):
    with create_session() as session:
        triggered_by = (
            session.query(Log.dttm, Log.dag_id, Log.execution_date, Log.owner)
            .filter(Log.dag_id == "killer_dag", Log.event == "trigger")
            .order_by(Log.dttm.desc())
            .first()[3]
        )
    logging.info(
        f"'{triggered_by}' triggered the Killer_dag. Getting PID for the termination."
    ) ....etc and the error is File "/app/dags/utils/utils.py", line 21, in kill_query
    .first()[3]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Keep in mind that if you don't actually trigger the DAG (either manually or via the scheduler) there wont be any `Log` to query. Running `airflow tasks test ..` won't create any record with `Log.event == "trigger"`. So before further debugging, make sure that actually exists a Log to query, you can do it by browsing the UI as explained above.

Comment: In order to avoid `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` when there are no results in the query, you could change the query to use `scalar()` again: `           session.query(Log.owner)
            .filter(Log.dag_id == "killer_dag", Log.event == "trigger")
            .order_by(Log.dttm.desc())
            .limit(1)
            .scalar()`   . Im adding this to the original answer for better reading.

Comment: You really helped me and using dttm solved the issue entirely. Thank you once again for your help! Wow.